# Can someone help me with this command im trying to make?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I'm trying to make a suggestion command but a unique one. The suggestion command needs to send the suggestion through a webhook to the channel. I tried making it with the say command but I don't know how to use webhooks. If anyone could help me, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Here is the code:

```
async def suggestion(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('...', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
        embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
        embed.add_field(name="Nouvelle suggestion !", value=ctx.message.content.lstrip(f"{prefix}suggest"))
        embed.set_footer(text=f"""{ctx.message.author} • {datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")}""",
                         icon_url=str(ctx.message.author.avatar_url))
        await webhook.send(embed=embed, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

I got it from stackoverflow. I think it's outdated, and that's why I'm getting errors.

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command suggestion:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/dasdasdasd/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 41, in suggestion
    webhook = Webhook.from_url('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/96xxxxxxxxx80/xxxxx/kwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyOBRc6U', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
NameError: name 'Webhook' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/runner/dasdasdasd/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
      File "/home/runner/dasdasdasd/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
      File "/home/runner/dasdasdasd/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'Webhook' is not defined
```

Modules:

```
import discord, requests, discord_webhook
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_webhook import DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook
from discord import Embed
from discord.utils import escape_markdown, escape_mentions
import requests, aiohttp, datetime
import random
import re
from random import randint
import signal
import sys
import asyncio
import urllib.parse
import base64
from random import choice
import os
import datetime, time
from asyncio import sleep as s
import giphy_client
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from discord.utils import get
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
import random
import string
```

The error in the code:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIBi0.png

Comment: Can you provide the code? Then I can help you.

Comment: sure ill send it rn

Comment: async def suggestion(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('...', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
        embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
        embed.add_field(name="Nouvelle suggestion !", value=ctx.message.content.lstrip(f"{prefix}suggest"))
        embed.set_footer(text=f"""{ctx.message.author} • {datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")}""",
                         icon_url=str(ctx.message.author.avatar_url))
        await webhook.send(embed=embed, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

Comment: i got the code from another stack overflow thingy but im getting errors

Comment: here is the pastebin link -> https://pastebin.com/mQbHjnAz

Comment: why do you give code in the comment you can edit in your question.

Comment: oh i didn't know let me add it

Comment: Are you getting any errors while running the file?

Comment: let me add the error

Comment: You need to `import Webhook` so it will be in the current namespace.

Comment: I don’t know what package `Webhook` is in…

Comment: let me edit and add the modules

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Webhook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Webhook'

Comment: `from discord import Webhook`. docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook

Answer (score 1):

Try these imports instead:

```py
import discord, requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Webhook, AsyncWebhookAdapter
from discord import Embed
from discord.utils import escape_markdown, escape_mentions
import requests, aiohttp, datetime
import random
import re
from random import randint
import signal
import sys
import asyncio
import urllib.parse
import base64
from random import choice
import os
import datetime, time
from asyncio import sleep as s
import giphy_client
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from discord.utils import get
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
import random
import string
```